# How do you programatically render a views exposed filter form block in a tpl in Drupal 6?

Tags: views, 6

I am trying to setup my views exposed filter form block in a custom tpl. How do I do this programatically? Note: My views setup display type is a page with a separate exposed filter form block.

Answer (score 1):

views_embed_view displays the whole views block. Therefore in your template you put:

```
print views_embed_view('most_read_today', 'block_1');
```

If you are needing to pass arguments to your 'exposed filter', [add a 3rd argument](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_embed_view/6).